# How to test for my callback function with Jasmine?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have an angular service class : -

// Loads the user data from firebase

```
this.init = function(readyCallback) {
  var log = angular.extend({}, this._log);
  log.funct = 'init';

  var fireRef = new Firebase('https://luminous-inferno-1740.firebaseio.com/' + $rootScope.clientName);
  config = $firebase(fireRef.child('config')).$asObject();
  userState = $firebase(fireRef.child('userState').child($rootScope.userName)).$asObject();

  Promise.all([config.$loaded(), userState.$loaded()]).
    then(
      function() {
        if(config == null || Object.keys(config).length < 4) {
          log.message = 'Invalid config';
          $log.error(log);
          return;
        }

        if(!userState.userProperties) {
          userState.userProperties = {};
        }

        if(!userState.contentProperties) {
          userState.contentProperties = {};
        } 

        log.message = 'User Properties: ' + JSON.stringify(userState.userProperties);
        $log.debug(log);

        log.message = 'Content Properties: ' + JSON.stringify(userState.contentProperties);
        $log.debug(log);

        log.message = 'Loaded user data from firebase';
        $log.debug(log);
        readyCallback();
      },
      function() {
        log.message = 'Unable to load user data from firebase';
        $log.error(log);
      }
    );
};
```

I am trying to unit test this service using jasmine:-

my unit test is :-

```
// load the service's module


 beforeEach(function() {
    module('triggerTips');
  });

// instantiate service


 var userData;
  var $firebase;
  var log;
  var $rootScope;
  beforeEach(inject(function (_userData_, _$rootScope_, $log, _$firebase_, $http) {
    userData = _userData_;
    $firebase=_$firebase_;
    log = $log;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $rootScope.clientName = 'testClient';
    $rootScope.userName = 'userDataTest';
    $rootScope.userGroupName = 'testGroup';
    $rootScope.env = 'dev';
  }));

  it('should load correctly', function () {
    expect(!!userData).toBe(true);
  });


  describe('initial configuration for the test user', function () {

      beforeEach(function(done){
          var config = {
                'Apache 404' : {
                  content : {
                    type : 'tip',
                    template : 'yesNo',
                    text : 'Are you searching for status code 404?',
                    yesText : 'Try our more accurate <a href="https://www.loggly.com/docs/search-query-language/#field_names" target="_blank">field search</a>',
                    attachTo : '#inputBox right',
                    yesActions : {
                      0 : {
                          type : 'replaceSubstring',
                          target : '#inputBox',
                          value : 'apache.status:404',
                          match : '404'
                        }
                    }
                  },
                  conditions : {
                    0 : {
                        type : 'valueChange',
                        target : '#inputBox',
                        textMatch : '(^|([\\s]+))404(([\\s]+)|$)',
                        preventSubmit : true
                      },
                    1 : {
                        type : 'contentPropertyLessThan',
                        propertyName : 'timesShown',
                        compareVal : 3
                      }
                  }
                }
          };

          var fireRef = new Firebase('https://luminous-inferno-1740.firebaseio.com/' + $rootScope.clientName);
          var fireSync = $firebase(fireRef);
          fireSync.$set({'config' : config});

          userData.init();
          jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 2000;
      });

      it('should have a success log', function(done) {
          setTimeout(function() {
              expect(log.debug.logs.length > 9).toBe(true);
              expect(log.debug.logs.length).toBeGreaterThan(2);
              done();
            }, 2500);
      });

      it('should have a valid config', function () {
          expect(Object.keys(userData.getConfig()).length == 1).toBe(true);
      });
  });
```

I am new with this I am receiving an error :

Can somebody help me providing working example of my code ?

Comment: You're missing the error message you received. Also, it will be much easier to answer if you simplify the code you are working with.

Comment: Can you please help me. i am new with karma

Comment: I can't help until you simplify the code snippet.